# Combine strings from exception errors

Tags: python

I am looking to combine the messages from errors within an exception object.

```
for error in exc.errors:
    message += error.message
```

works but ideally I would like to add a space as well.

```
for error in exc.errors:
    message += " {}".format(error.message)
```

but I really feel there must be a much cleaner/pythonic way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this:

```py
message = " ".join([error.message for error in exec.errors])
```